# Cannot get input in a subprocess started by a Swift program

Tags: swift

The problem is, I have a program written in Swift, in it I started a subprocess to run a Ruby script, in the Ruby script I cannot get the input (which works well if I started the script in a Ruby program).

I prepared a demo that quickly demonstrates this problem, be sure to check it out: https://github.com/axl411/swift-get-input-problem.

UPDATE:

I also posted a bug here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4029

Comment: Did you set [`standardInput`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/process/1411576-standardinput) of your `Process`?

Comment: No, because according to documentation, if I does not set it, it will inherit from the process created it. Also, in Xcode it works, so the code should be OK.